# Angular Change Scope variable from Rootscope function - how to do that?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

There is a common function in my rootscope. I have more than one controller which is using the same function.

I need to change the Scope variable from Rootscope Function.

http://jsfiddle.net/qkZHG/

In JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .run(function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.rs = new Date();

 $rootScope.changeRsFromRs = function() {
  $rootScope.rs = new Date();
};

 //Not Working
 $rootScope.changeSFromRs = function() {
  $scope.s = new Date();
};
})
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
   $scope.s = new Date();

  $scope.changeSFromS = function() {
    $scope.s = new Date();
};

$scope.changeRsFromS = function() {
    $rootScope.rs = new Date();
};
});
```

In Html ,

```
<button class="not-working" ng-click='changeSFromRs()'>Change Scope value from Rootscope</button>
```

Comment: why do you think this should be possible? $scope is not defined in your changeSFromRs function.

Comment: This is not possible as when you go back to your rootScope then the contextual scope is undefined. Probably what you want to achieve can be done using angular services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using this keyword.

http://jsfiddle.net/qkZHG/3/

In JS :

```
$rootScope.changeSFromRs = function(scope) {
  scope.s = new Date();
};
```

In HTML :

```
<button class="not-working" ng-click='changeSFromRs(this)'>Change Scope value from Rootscope</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not possible, since your $rootScope does not have any reference of the scope, neither is it "meant" to do that.

You can inject $rootscope into your controller and bind to it, if that helps.

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.var = $rootScope.var2;
});
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just call the rootScope function?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.rs = new Date();
    $rootScope.updateDate = function() {
       $rootScope.rs = new Date();
    };
});

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
}]);
```

Idieally this would be better if you make a service for this.

```
myApp.service('DateService', function() {
        return {
            getDate: function() {
                return new Date();
            }
        };
    });
```

See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkZHG/1/)

Comment: +1 for the solution inside service... if possible, you should always avoid using rootscope

Comment: yes. You are right. its better to use service. But for the posted question, see my answer